# How to connect from C# web applications to a SQL Server 2008 R2 database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, database-connection

I have created a web application form with 3 text boxes for entering name, Id and address into a table in SQL Server 2008 R2 database with the database name `mydb.mdf` and table `table1` with column names `name,id` and `address`..

So how to code the submit button as to all my entered entries into the form will be updated into the SQL Server database table on clicking the submit button. Visual Studio version is 2012... plz help

Comment: what have you done till now?
Any codes?

Comment: well , i have just done the basics like entries in text boxes but i don't know how to establish a connection

Comment: Try to do some homework before asking questions.

Comment: i'm just asking how to setup the connection between the database and visual studio not asking the whole code @ricky

Comment: string connetionString = null;
            SqlConnection cnn ;
            connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password";
            cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
            try
            {
                cnn.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("Connection successful");
                cnn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
            }

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Connect()
{
    SqlConnection connection;
    server = Server Name
    database = Database Name
    uid = Username
    password = Password
    string connectionString;
    connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

    connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        connection.Open();
    }
}
```

Here's how you connect to a SQL Server database.

Comment: You could also use the [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) to handle the creation of a valid connection string - this would avoid any typos etc.